# Does TCP socket receive data in the same way as it was sent?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

If a TCP client sends chunks of data like this:

```
CHUNK1: 50 bytes of data
CHUNK2: 10 bytes of data
CHUNK3: 20 bytes of data
CHUNK4: 30 bytes of data
CHUNK5: 40 bytes of data
```

will the TCP server then receive the data in the same way:

```
CHUNK1: 50 bytes of data
CHUNK2: 10 bytes of data
CHUNK3: 20 bytes of data
CHUNK4: 30 bytes of data
CHUNK5: 40 bytes of data
```

or might it arrive like this instead:

```
CHUNK1: 80 bytes of data
CHUNK2: 30 bytes of data
CHUNK3: 40 bytes of data
```

The reason why I am asking is because each chunk is a self-contained message (on the client side) which contains some signaling and a data payload. So I'm wondering if I have to parse the data stream on the server side (if the data doesn't arrive in the same way as it was sent) to reconstruct the messages on the server side.

Comment: The second. TCP is a stream protocol, there are no message bounderies, only the order of delivery is guaranteed.

Comment: Only the order? What about the delivery? Isn't that guaranteed with TCP?

Comment: Nothing is guaranteed, except that you cannot receive an octet ("byte")  before having received all the previous octets.

Comment: So the only advantage of using TCP is that the order is guaranteed?

Comment: TCP guarantees that _if_ some octets are received, _then_ these octets are received without errors (as inserts, deletes or replaces), no more. If you need message boundaries preserving, consider switching to SCTP, it's much easier to use.

Comment: @netch : does SCTP guarantee that messages arrive in the right order?

Comment: i see that it does. Great advice Netch. thank you

Comment: @Netch : I tried out SCTP using http://www.sctp.de/sctp-download.html . I couldn't get any of the examples to work and the documentation is quite sparse. I was able to compile and build the code. So I tried to build the client example and the echo server example. The client hung and the echo server didn't respond to anything.

Comment: @user1884325 https://github.com/netch80/micro/tree/master/tests/sctp some working examples.

Comment: @Netch Thank you - aren't those examples using native SCTP support on a non-Windows platform? The problem I'm having is that the examples provided with the Windows SCTP code (link above) don't seem to work.

Comment: These examples were for FreeBSD but work under Linux. Sorry, no Windows experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `recv` and `send` networking calls might return fewer number of bytes sent/received than specified. You may want to have such function which receives exactly specified number of bytes.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

int readall(int s, char *buf, int *len)
{
    int total = 0;        // how many bytes we've read
    int bytesleft = *len; // how many we have left to read
    int n = -1;

    while(total < *len) {
        n = read(s, buf+total, bytesleft, 0);
        if (n <= 0)  { break; }  
        total += n;
        bytesleft -= n;
    }

    *len = total; // return number actually read here

    return (n<=0)?-1:0; // return -1 on failure, 0 on success
}
```

You can write a similar `sendall` function too. Then you use `sendall` to send first two bytes which specify message length for example, and then `sendall` the message. You do same on receiving side, first `readall` the message length, then the message.

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a stream-oriented protocol. "Message boundaries" are not preserved. The standard does not know what a message is.

Search for "TCP message framing" to find what you need.

Comment: Is it correct that 'message boundaries' are preserved with UDP? But then I have no guarantee that the sent packets are actually received (unless I implement some kind of signaling between client and server), right?

Comment: Both correct. Search for "TCP message framing" to find what you need.